# How to run migrations in custom sequence

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

Ex. I have two tables, the `checkers` table and `users` table.

I want to migrate the `users` table first because the `checkers` table has a foreign key on 'users' table but the `checkers` table executes first.

I use `php artisan migrate` command.

Do I have to run the `users` table first manually or there is a better way?

[-> Laravel Foreign Key Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys)

Comment: Just create two migrations. If you have multiple migrations (> multiple files) they will be ran in the order you created them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer.

> The number before the migration file name is a date time, make your user migration and earlier time and your should be good

[Source - http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10246](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10246)